# What can I do to calculate the gravitational potential of an infinite filament that I haven't tried here?

Tags: classical-mechanics, potential

I'm trying to calculate the gravitational potential caused by an infinitely long filament of uniform linear density $\lambda$. This is what I've done ($\vec{r}$ is the position vector pointing to any point in space, $\vec{r'}$ is the position vector of the mass distribution, which in this case will just be along the $z$ axis).

$$\Phi_{G}=-G\int_{0}^{M}\frac{dm}{|\vec{r}-\vec{r'}|}=-G\lambda \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{dz'}{\sqrt{r^2-2rz'+z'^2}}=-G\lambda\left[\ln{(z'-r)}\right]_{-\infty}^\infty$$ which if plugged on something like Symbolab, gives $\ln(-1)$. Not a very promising result.

Did I do anything wrong? If not, what can I do to deal with these infinities?

Answer (score 0):

The mistake is that you can't take the limit of infinite length on both ends individually, you have to make the computation for a finite rod-length first, and then take the limit of infinite length in the result for the finite rod, the infinities may cancel then (in general it is also a possible outcome that the potential around some configuration of infinite mass is not finite!).

Another technique that may help is to compute the field strength via the Gauß theorem plus symmetry considerations and derive the potential from the field strength.

And another problem is that your second expression for the integrand is wrong. $\left| \vec r - \vec r' \right|$ does not equal $\sqrt{ (r - z')^2 }$ but rather $\sqrt{(z' - z)^2 + \rho^2}$ (where $\rho$ is the distance to the cylinder axis – of course you can choose $z = 0$ by a coordinate change).

Comment: Alright, that makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: And I remarked on another problem (that I didn't see before because I just paid attention to the cancelling of infinities problem).